# IPython not recognising changes to class definition

Tags: python, ipython

IPython does not seem to recognise changes made to class definition after the script is run the first time. Changes to stand-alone functions work fine, just not changes to the class functions.  The only way I can get it to work is to force a %reset. 
Am I going crazy or does this really work this way (not update changes to a class in the script)?  Is there a work around ? I have tried [autoreload](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html):

%load_ext autoreload

%autoreload 2

but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you reinitialize instances of the class? IPython should catch changes in class definition, but it won't update existing instances.

Comment: No, I have not reinitialized instances. If you couldn't guess from my original question then you will probably deduce by now that I am a rookie at this (doing an edX course).  My next question is, how do I reinitialize instances?  Just call them up with the set of initial variables again?

Comment: Wow. So I just figured this out based on alexey's guidance, I can have two different instances of a class with two different sets of code/instructions/attributes!? I can call one instance, change the code, call the other instance, and each has it's own properties/methods. So somehow the whole class code set is retained by each instance? One before the change, and one after?<br>Pardon me for being naive, but I would have thought that the methods etc. would have been stored in only one central repository (ie the current one) rather than two or more different ones.<br>

Comment: Does each instance retain it's own particular set of code, even two instances instantiated against the same version of code? Or is my understanding of what's going on here completely off the mark?

Comment: In python everything is an object. So when you create a new class its object is placed somewhere in the memory and a link is stored in the current scope. When you create a new instance the ref to its class stored in `__class__` attribute. It doesn't mind the class name, just a reference. If you create a new class it obtains a new location in memory and overwrites the previous definition in the scope. Every new instance will be associated with a new class definition. But the previous one will be still available with direct link.

Comment: The class definition is stored once, and each instance stores a reference to that class, which is effectively a reference to the location in which the definition is stored?  If you have three instances of a class (without changing the definition), they are each just their own reference to the same `__class__` location (just like a=2, b=a, c=b are all references to the same memory location)?

Answer (score 0):

Alexey's advice points to the answer, the variables assigned to a class must be reassigned or reinitialised after changing the class definition, otherwise they continue to retain the class properties and methods from before the change.